# Can I synchronize Things for Mac with Dropbox?

Tags: macos, dropbox, things-for-mac

I am a fan of *Things for Mac* and have been using on my MacBook Pro. I just bought another Mac and was wondering about sharing across the computers.

My thought was to use dropbox to create the database file that *Things* references. I have successfully done this and they both instances of Things refer to the same database file.

The problem is that they two instances don't seem to be communicating properly. I want it to work such that when I change tasks on one computer, it updates when I open on the other.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. You just have to be sure that you are only working with one instance open at a time. Both doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah. I've done the exact same thing using Dropbox. To avoid problems I usually keep Things running only on my Macbook which I also use to sync with Things for iPhone. But when the Macbook is asleep, it's safe to fire up Things on my other mac and access the same, up-to-date data.

Answer (score 0):

Things syncing is now handled by [Things Cloud](http://culturedcode.com/things/cloud/) using iCloud, for both OSX and iOS versions.